# PSEXESVC Not Self Deleting and Not deletable by Any Admin User

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, psexec

I run psexec.exe locally to handle a process on multiple remote servers/DC's.  One server in particular has begun to experience an issue where after one successful run, the PSEXESVC.exe remains and no further psexec's can be run.

`sc delete PSEXESVC` reports that the specified service does not exist as an installed service.

I am unable delete PSEXESVC from C:\Windows directly.  I have administrator rights/permissions yet it is not my server.  The actual administrator is also unable to delete PSEXESVC.

Comment: The service may likely be pending deletion.  Have you rebooted the server?

Comment: Likely it is still running. Whatever task you’re kicking off is not completing. The service is “deleted” (from the registry) but the executable it still running and the file is locked.